# How to get 'src' attribute of my image in webview and pass it via intent?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm showing some images from my assets folder using webview and i want to define an onclick listener for my specific image so when user clicks on it, it shows in a new intent in full scale.

```
    private void showDescription() {
    final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + main_menu_title + "/" + sub_menu_title + "/index.html" );
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick()
        {

        }
    }, "ok");

}
```

this is my image and onclick function for it:

```
<img src="img_desc00.png" alt="Description" style="width:500px; height:500px;
```

margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block; " onclick="ok.performClick();">

I want to get src attribute of the image so i can pass it via intent to show in another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onclick attribute you can access to the current html element with the keyword this and to his attributes with him getAttribute method so you can do:

```
<img src="..." onclick="ok.performClick(this.getAttribute('src'))">
```